# I want to add a see more button after certain amount of li and which same ul class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three ul tags with similar class, inside those tags are random amount of li tags, what I want to do is show a see more link after certain amount of li tags that display the remaining tag and a less that hides them

here is my html

```
         <ul class="tips-detail-list" style="margin-bottom: 30px">

                                     <li><b>Type :</b> Hill Fort</li>
                                    <li><b>Grade : </b>Medium</li>
                                    <li><b> Endurance Level:</b>  Moderate</li>
                                    <li><b>Height :</b> Approx. 4255 ft. ASL</li>
                                    <li><b>Distance From Borivali : </b> 200 KM </li>
                                    <li><b>Travel time : </b> 4.30 hrs  </li>


                                </ul>

                                <h3>Pick Up Points</h3>
                                <ul class="tips-detail-list" style="margin-bottom:30px">

                                <li>11: PM – SGNP, Borivali </li>
                                <li>11:30 PM – Andheri, WEH</li>
                                <li>11:45 PM - Kalanagar, Bandra  </li>
                                <li>12:00 - Sion Station</li>
                                <li>12:15 - Chheda Nagar, Ghatkopar</li>
                                <li>12:30 AM – Teen hath Naka, Thane</li>
                                <li>01:00 AM - Vatika Hotel, Kalyan</li>


                                </ul>



                                <h3 style="font-family: poppins">Itinerary</h3>
                                <!-- <ul class="tips-detail-list"> -->
                                <ul class="tips-detail-list">
                                    <li>Assemble at start point SGNP, Borivali at 11 PM</li>
                                    <li>Tea and snacks break on the way</li>
                                    <li>Reach base village at 4 AM (9th July)</li>
                                    <li>Start trekking at 5 AM after stretching, briefing and breakfast</li>
                                    <li>Reach top of the fort by 8:00 AM</li>
                                    <li>Descend down to Samrad village reach by 12 noon</li>
                                    <li>Lunch at 1 PM in Samrad Village</li>
                                    <li>Reach Mumbai by 8 PM</li><br><br>
                                </ul>
                                <!-- </ul> -->

                                <h3>Things to Carry</h3>

                                <ul class="tips-detail-list">


                                  <li>Torch with extra batteries</li>                       
                                  <li>ID Card</li> 
                                  <li>Camera (Optional)</li> 
                                  <li>Snacks</li> 
                                  <li>Extra Pair of Clothes</li>
                                  <li>Clean napkin or small towel</li>
                                  <li>Cap, sunglasses, scarf </li>                                  
                                  <li>Haversack or Backpack</li>
                                  <li>Please carry medicines if you need any</li>
                                  <li>Hand Sanitizer</li>
                                  <li>Old Newspaper / Sleeping Mat</li>
                                  <li>Sleeping bag / Blanket</li>
                                </ul>
```

I was trying to get the length of li tags in each ul class by applying the following code

```
var minimized_elements1 = $('.tips-detail-list');


minimized_elements1.each(function () {

    public
    var t = $(this).children().length;
    console.log(t);
});
```

I am stuck here and don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

At first check if the element length is greater then certain number or not. It the element length is greater then certain number then append the see more and hide all the elements after the index.

```js
var minimized_elements1 = $('.tips-detail-list');


minimized_elements1.each(function () {

    var t = $(this).children().length;
    if (t > 5) {
      $(this).append('<p class="see">See more</a>');
      $(this).find('li').slice(5).hide();
    }
});

$(minimized_elements1).on('click', '.see', function(){
  $(this).parent().find('li').show();
  $(this).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tips-detail-list" style="margin-bottom: 30px">

                                     <li><b>Type :</b> Hill Fort</li>
                                    <li><b>Grade : </b>Medium</li>
                                    <li><b> Endurance Level:</b>  Moderate</li>
                                    <li><b>Height :</b> Approx. 4255 ft. ASL</li>
                                    <li><b>Distance From Borivali : </b> 200 KM </li>
                                    <li><b>Travel time : </b> 4.30 hrs  </li>


                                </ul>

                                <h3>Pick Up Points</h3>
                                <ul class="tips-detail-list" style="margin-bottom:30px">

                                <li>11: PM – SGNP, Borivali </li>
                                <li>11:30 PM – Andheri, WEH</li>
                                <li>11:45 PM - Kalanagar, Bandra  </li>
                                <li>12:00 - Sion Station</li>
                                <li>12:15 - Chheda Nagar, Ghatkopar</li>
                                <li>12:30 AM – Teen hath Naka, Thane</li>
                                <li>01:00 AM - Vatika Hotel, Kalyan</li>


                                </ul>



                                <h3 style="font-family: poppins">Itinerary</h3>
                                <!-- <ul class="tips-detail-list"> -->
                                <ul class="tips-detail-list">
                                    <li>Assemble at start point SGNP, Borivali at 11 PM</li>
                                    <li>Tea and snacks break on the way</li>
                                    <li>Reach base village at 4 AM (9th July)</li>
                                    <li>Start trekking at 5 AM after stretching, briefing and breakfast</li>
                                    <li>Reach top of the fort by 8:00 AM</li>
                                    <li>Descend down to Samrad village reach by 12 noon</li>
                                    <li>Lunch at 1 PM in Samrad Village</li>
                                    <li>Reach Mumbai by 8 PM</li><br><br>
                                </ul>
                                <!-- </ul> -->

                                <h3>Things to Carry</h3>

                                <ul class="tips-detail-list">


                                  <li>Torch with extra batteries</li>                       
                                  <li>ID Card</li> 
                                  <li>Camera (Optional)</li> 
                                  <li>Snacks</li> 
                                  <li>Extra Pair of Clothes</li>
                                  <li>Clean napkin or small towel</li>
                                  <li>Cap, sunglasses, scarf </li>                                  
                                  <li>Haversack or Backpack</li>
                                  <li>Please carry medicines if you need any</li>
                                  <li>Hand Sanitizer</li>
                                  <li>Old Newspaper / Sleeping Mat</li>
                                  <li>Sleeping bag / Blanket</li>
                                </ul>
```

Comment: I am sorry but I believe I have not explained the problem properly

Comment: for example if the li element in the ul is 15, I want to show 7 first and then when clicked on (see more) it will show the remaining  8 with a less button which will hide the element the (see more) has shown

Comment: why are all my questions getting downvoted? You seems to have some reputation can you tell why this is happeneing>